# TensorFlow.js: "Error: Weights are not set" when loading converted model with BatchNormalization Layers

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm porting to TF.js a model converted from Keras with its pretrained weights.
I followed the instructions on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras) and saved the weights from a local path.

When I'm initializing my model by loading the `.json` file, with tfjs-node 1.7.1, I get the following error:

```
(node:39703) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 152 of 197 weights are not set: conv1_1/3x3_s1/bn/gamma,conv1_1/3x3_s1/bn/beta,conv1_1/3x3_s1/bn/moving_mean,conv1_1/3x3_s1/bn/moving_variance,conv2_a_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv2_a_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv2_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv2_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv2_a_3x3/bn/gamma,conv2_a_3x3/bn/beta,conv2_a_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv2_a_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv2_a_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv2_a_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv2_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv2_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv2_a_1x1_proj/bn/gamma,conv2_a_1x1_proj/bn/beta,conv2_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_mean,conv2_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_variance,conv2_b_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv2_b_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv2_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv2_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv2_b_3x3/bn/gamma,conv2_b_3x3/bn/beta,conv2_b_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv2_b_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv2_b_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv2_b_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv2_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv2_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv3_a_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv3_a_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv3_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv3_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv3_a_3x3/bn/gamma,conv3_a_3x3/bn/beta,conv3_a_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv3_a_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv3_a_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv3_a_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv3_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv3_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv3_a_1x1_proj/bn/gamma,conv3_a_1x1_proj/bn/beta,conv3_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_mean,conv3_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_variance,conv3_b_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv3_b_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv3_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv3_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv3_b_3x3/bn/gamma,conv3_b_3x3/bn/beta,conv3_b_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv3_b_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv3_b_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv3_b_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv3_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv3_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv3_c_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv3_c_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv3_c_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv3_c_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv3_c_3x3/bn/gamma,conv3_c_3x3/bn/beta,conv3_c_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv3_c_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv3_c_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv3_c_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv3_c_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv3_c_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv4_a_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv4_a_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv4_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv4_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv4_a_3x3/bn/gamma,conv4_a_3x3/bn/beta,conv4_a_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv4_a_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv4_a_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv4_a_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv4_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv4_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv4_a_1x1_proj/bn/gamma,conv4_a_1x1_proj/bn/beta,conv4_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_mean,conv4_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_variance,conv4_b_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv4_b_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv4_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv4_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv4_b_3x3/bn/gamma,conv4_b_3x3/bn/beta,conv4_b_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv4_b_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv4_b_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv4_b_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv4_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv4_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv4_c_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv4_c_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv4_c_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv4_c_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv4_c_3x3/bn/gamma,conv4_c_3x3/bn/beta,conv4_c_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv4_c_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv4_c_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv4_c_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv4_c_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv4_c_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv5_a_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv5_a_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv5_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv5_a_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv5_a_3x3/bn/gamma,conv5_a_3x3/bn/beta,conv5_a_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv5_a_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv5_a_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv5_a_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv5_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv5_a_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv5_a_1x1_proj/bn/gamma,conv5_a_1x1_proj/bn/beta,conv5_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_mean,conv5_a_1x1_proj/bn/moving_variance,conv5_b_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv5_b_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv5_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv5_b_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv5_b_3x3/bn/gamma,conv5_b_3x3/bn/beta,conv5_b_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv5_b_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv5_b_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv5_b_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv5_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv5_b_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance,conv5_c_1x1_reduce/bn/gamma,conv5_c_1x1_reduce/bn/beta,conv5_c_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_mean,conv5_c_1x1_reduce/bn/moving_variance,conv5_c_3x3/bn/gamma,conv5_c_3x3/bn/beta,conv5_c_3x3/bn/moving_mean,conv5_c_3x3/bn/moving_variance,conv5_c_1x1_increase/bn/gamma,conv5_c_1x1_increase/bn/beta,conv5_c_1x1_increase/bn/moving_mean,conv5_c_1x1_increase/bn/moving_variance
    at new ValueError (./AudioReco/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/errors.js:68:28)
    at LayersModel.Container.loadWeights (./AudioReco/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/container.js:569:23)
    at ./AudioReco/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/models.js:303:27
    at step (./AudioReco/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/models.js:54:23)
    at Object.next (./AudioReco/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/models.js:35:53)
    at fulfilled (./AudioReco/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/models.js:26:58)
```

I understand this has something to do with all the Batch Normalization layers the model uses but **how do I properly restore the Gammas, Betas, Moving Mean & Moving Average to each of them?**

---

Model taken from the work of [Wei Xie from VoxCeleb](https://github.com/WeidiXie/VGG-Speaker-Recognition). The original weights of the model [can be found on his Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M_SXoW1ceKm3LghItY2ENKKUn3cWYfZm) and the converted ones in the `.json` format can be found [on this link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jhiVzWhmDZeq9q_pn22epYJdTYeXvCPl).

#### Code ran:

**model.js**

```js
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

class VGGVox_Model {
    constructor() {
        this.model;
    }

    async init() {
        // Loading the custom layers
        require('./layers/VladPooling');
        require('./layers/Lambda');

        this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://resources/model/model.json', false);
        this.model.summary();
    }
}

(async function main() {
  const myModel = new VGGVox_Model();
  myModel.init();
})();
```

**VladPooling.js**

```js
const tf = require('../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

class VladPooling extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
        this.kCenters = config.kCenters;
        this.gCenters = config.gCenters;
        this.mode = config.mode;
    }


    compute_output_shape(input_shape) {
        return (input_shape[0][0], this.kCenters * input_shape[0][input_shape[0].length - 1])
    }

    build(input_shape) {
        this.cluster = this.addWeight(
            'centers',
            [ this.kCenters + this.gCenters, input_shape[0][input_shape[0].length - 1] ],
            'float32',
            'orthogonal');
        this.built = true;
    }


    call(inputs, kwargs) {
        return tf.tidy(() => {
            console.log('call')
        });
    }


    getConfig() {
        const baseConfig = super.getConfig();
        const config = {
            kCenters: this.kCenters,
            gCenters: this.gCenters,
            mode: this.mode
        };
        Object.assign(config, baseConfig);
        return config;
    }


    static get className() {
        return 'VladPooling';
    }
}
tf.serialization.registerClass(VladPooling);
exports.vlad_pooling = VladPooling;
```

**Lambda.js**

```js
const tf = require('../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

class Lambda extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
        if (config.name === undefined) {
            config.name = ((+new Date) * Math.random()).toString(36); //random name from timestamp in case name hasn't been set
        }
        this.name = config.name;
        this.lambdaFunction = config.function;
    }

    call(input) {
        return tf.tidy(() => {
            let result = null;
            eval(this.lambdaFunction);
            return result;
        });
    }

    computeOutputShape(inputShape) {
        return inputShape;
    }

    getConfig() {
        const config = super.getConfig();
        Object.assign(config, {
            lambdaFunction: this.lambdaFunction
        });
        return config;
    }

    static get className() {
        return 'Lambda';
    }
}
tf.serialization.registerClass(Lambda);
```

As for the two custom layers (Vlad Pooling and Lambda), I added them as well in the Google Drive folder. Lambda layer's code [was taken here](https://twitter.com/BenjaminWegener/status/1231010778100178945). I didn't include the call() of the Vlad Pooling yet since I couldn't check the outputs (model doesn't load).  Anyways, they are required because the model loading won't work without them.

Comment: I think the problem is with resnet backbone. BatchNormalization layers create a problem, I also had issues with senet50 model. Here is issue for tfjs repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3776

Comment: Hey ! Did you solve the problem? I'm having the same issue while loading YOLOv3 with mobilenet architecture ; same BatchNormalization layers issue !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `call` method of the `VladPoolingLayer` in python and js, the js method does not fully implement the VLadPoolingLayer of the python model. `call` is the method where the actual computation of the layer takes place. Consequently it should return a tensor whose shape matches what is returned by `computeOutputShape` (typo for VladPoolingLayer).

The lambda layer written was copied from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408840/custom-layer-multiple-input-issue-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-dty). There is a difference in the way the lambda layer was written compared to a normal lambda layer in python. So this lambda layer cannot be used as it is for the model here. The lambda layer of the `VGG-Speaker-Recognition` is doing a l2 normalization. Thus the layer can be written as following:

```
class lambdaLayer extends tf.layers.Layer {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config)
  }

  call(input) {
    return tf.layers.layerNormalization({axis: 1}).apply(input);
  }

  static get className() {
    return 'lambdaLayer';
  }

tf.serialization.registerClass(lambdaLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with YOLOv3 implemented in Keras. I successfully converted the keras model to tfjs and tried to load it using tf.loadLayersModel in a React app but it gave me the exact same error. I thought that it has something to do with the Batch Normalization layers but it was not the case.

The problem was actually with loading the model using loadLayersModel which I don't really know why it is. What I did is that I loaded the model using Keras and saved that model as .pb graph. Then I loaded the .pb using Tensorflow which was working fine. Next step was to convert the model using tensorflowjs_converter wrapper as tfjs_graph_model instead of tfjs_layers_model. Finally I tried to load the tfjs model using tf.loadGraphModel in React app and I got successful making the predictions. The code for converting .h5 model to .pb graph is given below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model, save_model
from keras import backend as K

def swish_activation(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(x) * x)

keras_model_path = "exported-models/model.h5/"
output_model_path = "exported-models/tf/"

def convert_keras_to_graph():
    model = load_model(keras_model_path, custom_objects={"hard_swish": swish_activation})
    model.summary()
    save_model(model, output_model_path)
    
    # check the model in tensorflow
    model = tf.saved_model.load(output_model_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert_keras_to_graph()
```

Now convert the graph in tensorflowjs format using the following cmd command:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model --saved_model_tags=serve --signature_name=serving_default exported-models\tf\ exported-models\tfjs --signature_name=serving_default
```

then in tensorflowjs, just load the model as given below:

```
const MODEL_URL: "http://localhost:8080/model/model.json",
const model = tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL)
      .then((model) => {
        console.log("model loaded: ", model);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("failed to load the model", error);
        throw error;
      });
```

**Note:** I've used http-server to place my model files including the weights (.bin) and model.json. This is a good practice to do so.

I hope this will work for you as it has worked for me; upvote this answer in case it has helped you so other can take benefit from it.